# Column 'keywords' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, sql

right, my code below is for taking rows from a MYSQL table and displaying them when the user input matches a keyword stored. recently i have decided it is stupid to have one long table and that sometimes, with similar keywords, the higher id comes out on top. if i have multiple tables, with specific sections like 'news' 'film' i should avoid the clash.

```
  <?php
  if( count($terms) == 0){ // If no terms entered, stop.
echo "No Search Terms Entered.";
    }else{      

 // connect
  $connect = mysql_connect("cust-mysql-123-05", "uthe_774575_0001", "rooney08") or   die('Couldn\'t connect to MySQL Server: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("theqlickcom_774575_db1", $connect ) or die('Couldn\'t Select the database: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));

/* Query Statement Building - Terms together */
$query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
$i = 0; 
foreach ($terms as $each) {
      if ($i++ !== 0){
            $query .= " AND ";
      }
      $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
}



$query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];

        echo '<h2><a class="ok" href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></h2>' . PHP_EOL;
                    echo '<p class="kk">' . $description . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;            
                    echo '<p><a class="okay" href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;
                      }
} else {
    /* Query Statement Building - Terms Separate */
    $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

    $terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($terms as $each) {
          if ($i++ !== 0){
                $query .= " OR ";
          }
          $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
    }

    $query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0) {

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                echo '<h2><a class="ok" href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></h2>' . PHP_EOL;
                echo '<p class="kk">' . $description . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;            
                echo '<p><a class="okay" href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '<br><br><span class="keywords">' . PHP_EOL;
                  }

    } else {
          echo "No results found for \"<b>{$k}</b>\""; 
    }
}
//disconnect
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Did you forget to paste the whole query? The query string looks incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a `keywords` field is in both scan and news tables, and your `where` clause is something like `where keywords = 'something'`

You should alter your filter to be `where scan.keywords = 'something'` if that is what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms); 

$keywords = join(',', terms);

$query = "SELECT * FROM scan WHERE keywords IN " . $keywords . " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM news WHERE keywords IN " . $keywords;
```

Comment: it is a search engine with the fields id,title,description,keywords,link and keywords is where the search engine uses. none of the above worked.

Comment: this is the query code:  $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

 $terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
 $i = 0; 
 foreach ($terms as $each) {
    if ($i++ !== 0){
    $query .= " AND ";
    }
    $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
 }

Comment: So you want it to return any rows from either table that have keywords that match your input?

Comment: MySQL Query Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM news WHERE keywords = is what i am receiving.

Comment: Post your complete code (including PHP) in your original post again please. It's very difficult to read in a comment. The code I wrote works fine for me.

Comment: Updated answer to what I think you want. Still hard to tell.

Comment: Did you look at my post? It has been updated. Yet you still updated your original. I didn't originally realize you wanted multiple keywords.

Comment: it doesnt work. i get an error, can u work with the updated code above? o.O

Comment: Please post the error. It seems that every single thing that goes wrong, I explicitly need to ask you to write it down. If you'd just written a detailed question in the first place, this would be easy.

Comment: do u really need an array to do this? i thought it would be a lot simpler and i was just missing out on something.

Comment: It depends entirely on what form your arguments (keywords) are in. Given the code above, it appears they are already in an array. I will rewrite my code with your exact variables. Please, in the future, provide detailed questions, and be willing to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Edited. If this doesn't work, I give up, you're giving me nothing to work with.

Comment: send me your email address and i'll send u a better description of my problem. start to finish. the edited code sends back an error.